# Replacement for wagtail.images.views.chooser.get_image_result_data method in Wagtail 4.1?

Tags: wagtail

I'm currently working on migrating my Wagtail project to version 4.1, and I've encountered an issue with the method wagtail.images.views.chooser.get_image_result_data which seems to be deprecated or removed in this version.

In previous versions of Wagtail, I used get_image_result_data to retrieve data about an image chosen in the Wagtail image chooser modal. However, it appears that this method is no longer available in Wagtail 4.1.

Could someone provide guidance on what method or approach should be used as a replacement for get_image_result_data in Wagtail 4.1? I need to retrieve image data from the image chooser modal, and any insights or code examples on how to accomplish this in the latest Wagtail version would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for any help or suggestions!

I've checked the Wagtail documentation and release notes, but I couldn't find explicit information about the replacement for get_image_result_data or how to achieve similar functionality in the newer version.